# Find number of bigrams without using (collections) library

Tags: python, string, counter

I am super new to python and I am currently really stuck.
My task is to figure out what bigrams there are in a given string and how often they appear.
It works using the collections library (you can see below exactly what I need) but I would like to see how it is done without using any libraries.

```
from collections import Counter 
      
string = "ababbababab"
result = Counter(string[x:x+2] for x in range(len(string) - 1)) 
print("Bigram Frequency : " + str(dict(result)))
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

First get the list of bigrams using your list comprehension:

```
bigrams = [string[x:x+2] for x in range(len(string) - 1)]
```

Then count the occurences of each bigram in the list:

```
bigram_counts = [bigrams.count(i) for i in bigrams]
```

Then we [zip](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) the bigram values with the counts and convert it to a dictionary. Duplicate keys cannot exist in dictionaries, so you will end up with a list of the unique bigrams and their corresponding counts:

```
result = dict(zip(bigrams,bigram_counts))
```

Output `print("Bigram Frequency : " + str(result))`:

```
Bigram Frequency : {'ab': 5, 'ba': 4, 'bb': 1}
```